# What does "the best day out" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [program](https://youtu.be/BHwW4WgMK-M) it's at 1 minute and 22 seconds. Here it is:

> So he was 15 meters short. It means he techically didn't complete the race. He was moved into third place, so he didn't bag the 8000 prize either. Not his **best day out**.

Comment: It follows the usage in "I had a good [**day out**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/day_out) at the races." If it was the best experience ever, I could say "It was the best day out I ever had." But if it was a disappointment, then it wasn't my "best day out".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple meaning is that he did not do well that day, and it's an understatement, since
he made what amounts to a bad mistake, ruining an otherwise good performance.

The entire phrase "Not his best day out!" is immediately understandable to a native English speaker, given the context, but I don't find exact dictionary support for that meaning of "out".

The phrase "day out" can mean a trip away from home for recreation, but the use here may have to do with the word "outing", in this sense:

[American Heritage Dictionary "outing" (4)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=outing)
4. An athletic competition or an appearance therein

Comment: [The 10th definition of **out** (adjective)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out) at Merriam-Webster is "engaged in or attempting a particular activity," which seems to fit here - it's not "his best day attempting to run a race."

Comment: @CanadianYankee  That does fit well.